# how to get the pixels of an image upto a particular radius in python

Tags: python, opencv, pixel

I'm trying to get the pixels of a particular point up to a radius as the circle in the image below. I know this is possible with contours, but contours are too slow and I need to get those pixels in real-time

image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVe9H.png

thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exploit the numpy `meshgrid` function together with some geometry:

```
h, w = # img size
y, x = # point location

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, h-1, h), np.linspace(0, w-1, w))
mask = (xx-x)**2 + (yy-y)**2 < radius**2
```

Then, to get the image pixels:

```
extracted_image = image * mask
```

Comment: oop. sorry my bad. I havent used stack overflow in a while lol